# How to get return output from another script?

Tags: python

How can i get the output from another script?

My first script to run:

```
from test2 import *
class Test():
    def todo (self):
        mult()
        addx()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().todo()
```

My second script  named `(test2.py`):

```
def mult():
    x= 2 * 4
    print(x)
    return x

def addx():
    sum = x + 2
    print("sum",sum)
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `addx()` you haven't declared `x`. I believe you want `x` from `mult`. So you can do something like this

```py
def addx():
    x = mult()
    sum = x + 2
    print("sum",sum)
```

Comment: can i get the value directly that the mult function returns  without adding the line x = mult() ?

Comment: not without calling `mult()`. You could however do `sum = mult() + 2`, that way not having to use the variable `x`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the return value of `mult`, to pass it to your second function `addx` as a parameter.

```
def todo (self):
    x = mult()
    addx(x)
```

I advise you to read the Python doc section about function : https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 0):

In `test2.py`, you have not defined `x`

```
def addx():
sum = x + 2
print("sum",sum)
```

The problem above is that the computer doesn't know what `x` is. You could pass it as a parameter:

```
def addx(x):
sum = x + 2
print("sum", sum)
```

and change your code to:

```
from test2 import *

class Test():
    def todo(self):
        addx(x=mult()) # whatever number you want

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().todo()
```